# How to pass data between activities stacked on each other for Android?

Tags: android

I have read several questions about how to pass data between 2 Activities in Android but nothing about how pass through several levels. I thought it would be straightforward when knowhing how to pass between 2 activies but strangely its not.

When I only pass from a child activity of the Main activity, everything works fine. But if I call an activity from the main activity, which in turn calls another activity I dont get any data passed through. Is the problem that the first called activity continues when I enter the top activity (i.e. activity called from first child activit to main) and is terminated before the result is returned?

As you can see I am trying to pass data in three layers but nothing gets passed down from the top activity to the MainActivity. Help appreciated.

```
    MainActivity.java

Intent constIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ConstantScreen.class);
startActivityForResult(constIntent, 1); //Start activity - Rest is done onActivityResult....
 break;
//
     ...........................
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data){
 super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

 if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
     constData= data.getStringExtra("constData2Main");
     String constStackData = switchSignPow(constData);
     inputStack.add(constStackData); inputDisplay.add(constData);
     cursorPosition += constData.length(); ++stackPosition; ++inputDisplayCursor;
     printInStack();
     inputText.setSelection(cursorPosition);
  }
}
```

Then the next activity:

```
   public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
  {
  super.onCreate(icicle);
  setContentView(R.layout.constants_menu);
  }

 String constData;
 public void onClick_Constant(View v){
   Intent intent = new Intent();
   Intent constIntent; 
    switch(v.getId()){
        case(R.id.MECHANICS):
    constIntent = new Intent(ConstantScreen.this, ClassicalMechanics.class); 
 startActivityForResult(constIntent, 2); 
             break;
        default:
            setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, intent);         
            break;
    }
    finish();
  }

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data){
 super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
 Intent intent = new Intent();

 if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
     constData= data.getStringExtra("constData");
     intent.putExtra("constData2Main", constData);
     setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
  }
 else{
     setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, intent);
  }
}
```

And finally the third, TOP activity:

```
  ClassicalMehcanics.java
  public class ClassicalMechanics extends Activity{
   public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
   {
  super.onCreate(icicle);
  setContentView(R.layout.classical_mechanics);
   }

    String constData;
   public void onClick_Constant(View v){
   Intent intent = new Intent();
    switch(v.getId()){
        case(R.id.CancelClassic):
             setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, intent);
             break;
        default:
constData= ((Button)findViewById(R.id.GRAVITYC)).getTag().toString();
            intent.putExtra("constData", constData);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);           
            break;
    }
    finish();
  } 
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your middle activity is where the issue's coming from. let me detail it out for you

when you start an activity for result, when you call finish on that activity `onActivityResult` will get called on whoever started the activity (lets call it the parent).

so you have Activity1 it starts Activity2 on click.
In Activity2 on click it starts Activity3 (Activity3 is started in a different thread) and finishes returning to Activity1. Activity3 on click you finish but because Activity2 is gone it doesn't know where to go.

what you need to do is wait on calling finish on Activity2 until Activity3 has returned.

Comment: Ofcourse, Thanks for good explanation! I placed the finish() in the  onActivityResult(...) at Activity2. Then the activity will have to wait as you explain.